# Adding bitmap mask to video on Android?

Tags: android, video

I've been looking for something about adding images to videos, but i haven't found what I wanted.

I'd like to add a bitmap/image mask in each frame of a video (it can be recorded or from SD), keeping the original sound, and save the video to the SD with the image.

Someone knows how it can be done in Android?

Thnx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**create a class that extends SurfaceView**

`public class PaintSurface extends SurfaceView {`
....

**In draw() function add code**

`@Override`
`public void draw(Canvas canvas) {`
     `super.draw(canvas);`
`canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap.img, bitmapPosX, bitmapPosY, null);`
`}
}`

**In onCreate function create an object of it.**

`videoView = new PaintSurface(this);`

**add it to your layout**

`RelativeLayout layut = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.lay);`

`layut.addView(videoView);`

**get a holder**

`videoHolder = videoView.getHolder();`

**set this holder's surface to the MediaRecorder object**

`recorder.setPreviewDisplay(videoHolder.getSurface());`

Comment: how to save that video?